# Problem with amscd package

Tags: amsmath

I'm trying to insert a commutative diagram into a report. I've loaded the amscd package, but I have a problem with its diagrams.

When I put up or down arrows, there are no problems. For example,

[image]

yields the correct diagram

But when I try to use left or right arrows it doesn't work.

This

[image]

only gives an isolated A in the left of the document. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get the expected output. Please try adding a minimal example. Are you perhaps using `babel`? With which language?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX: `amscd` is outdated and gives a not so good spacing in commutative diagrams. You should use the more recent `tikz-cd` instead

Comment: I was using babel in Spanish btw

Answer (score 1):

The `CD` environment can't work with `babel-spanish` without some countermeasures.

### Strategy 1: `\shorthandoff`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{CD}
A \\
@VVV \\
B
\end{CD}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\shorthandoff{<>}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> B
\end{CD}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

### Strategy 2: `es-noquoting`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{CD}
A \\
@VVV \\
B
\end{CD}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> B
\end{CD}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Consult the documentation of `spanish-babel` available with `texdoc spanish` or [on line](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.pdf)